# Retrieve list of containers with active service in JADE

Tags: pug, agent

Is there any way to ask DF agent to look for container with active service x?

I want to create 4 Containers, with default DF in main, one migrating agent in main, and one other agent in e.g. container 2.

Migrating agent should jump from one container to another and receive information about services active in this particular container, if service X is active, he needs to save this container on the list and check the rest.

After he checked all the containers, I want him to return to main one, and show numbers of containers in which he found service X.

I know how to make this migrating one, but I don't know if it's possible to check for active services in container.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is, that we cannot use main DF Agent to check for services in specific containers. Because of yellow pages which do not store this information, we would need one DF Agent for every container to check for services in the way I wanted.